# Can I track Adwords banner click from the other website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have an Adwords campaign, it sends users to Website-1.

And there is Website-2 and I want to track whether users that came to Website-2 have ever clicked on Adwords banner leading to Website-1 or not.

I could have set third-party cookies on Website-1 corresponding user is from Adwords and then get this info on Website-2. The problem is I don't have access to Website-1.

Is there any way to gain this info? I do have access to Adwords campaign, it's Google Account, Google Analytics on Website-2, it's Google Account and Website-2 itself. In other words, I have access to everything except Website-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use third-party redirect/counter, for example different ad-serving tool like AdForm, where you should be able to generate unique redirect URL in bulk for your campaign.

**Disadvantages:**

- you **loose gclid information** on AdWords tracking (because of redirect) and you need to use manual UTM tagging
- You need to **pay ad-serving fee** (few bucks for thousands of visitors) and someone to set it up
- You would **only know if that someone clicked** AdWords Ad, not really visited (beacuse you would count before that someone landed)

**In conclusion:** don't do it if you don't have direct access to GA of website-1

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in a pretty simple way, just set up Cross Domain tracking as described here:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

This will save original source information (including AdWords) wen user goes from Website-1 to Website-2. On Website-1 you need to edit Analytics code (on all pages) and add so called **autoLink**:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-2.com'] );
```

Make sure that on both websites youre using newest version of Google Analytics: Universal Analytics, because this will not work in older version